# Neo4j OGM RelationshipEntity is missing start or end node

Tags: java, neo4j, neo4j-ogm

When I try to set a export relation between two NodeEntities (BundleImpl and PackageFragmentImpl) I get the error message, that a start or end node is missing.
I appreciate any help. Thank you !

```
@NodeEntity
public class BundleImpl{

protected List<PackageFragmentImpl> exports;

@Relationship(type = "EXPORT", direction = "OUTGOING")
private Export exportRelation = new Export();

public Export getExport(){
    return exportRelation;
}

public void setExport(Export exportRelation){
    this.exportRelation = exportRelation;
}


@NodeEntity
public class PackageFragmentImpl {

protected BundleImpl bundle;

@Relationship(type = "EXPORT")
private Export exportRelation = new Export();

public Export getExport(){
    return exportRelation;
}

public void setExport(Export exportRelation){
    this.exportRelation = exportRelation;
}



@RelationshipEntity(type="EXPORT")
public class Export {

@GraphId 
Long id;

@StartNode
BundleImpl startBundle;

@EndNode
PackageFragmentImpl endPackageFrag;


public long timestamp;

public Export(){

}

public Export(BundleImpl startBundle, PackageFragmentImpl endPackageFrag, 
long timestamp){
    this.startBundle = startBundle;
    this.endPackageFrag = endPackageFrag;
    this.timestamp = timestamp;
}
// Getter & Setter
```

In the following part of my main method I set the relation between two nodes and check if they actually exist:

```
Export exportRelation = new Export(bundle, fragment, date);
bundle.setExport(exportRelation);
fragment.setExport(exportRelation);
```

The detailed error info I get after running the program is:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.neo4j.ogm.exception.MappingException: 
Relationship entity OSGiApplicationModel.impl.Export@1c491240 cannot have 
a missing start or end node
at org.neo4j.ogm.context.EntityGraphMapper.haveRelationEndsChanged(EntityGraphMapper.java:520)
at org.neo4j.ogm.context.EntityGraphMapper.getRelationshipBuilder(EntityGraphMapper.java:484)
at org.neo4j.ogm.context.EntityGraphMapper.link(EntityGraphMapper.java:447)
at org.neo4j.ogm.context.EntityGraphMapper.mapEntityReferences(EntityGraphMapper.java:390)
at org.neo4j.ogm.context.EntityGraphMapper.mapEntity(EntityGraphMapper.java:222)
at org.neo4j.ogm.context.EntityGraphMapper.mapRelatedEntity(EntityGraphMapper.java:717)
at org.neo4j.ogm.context.EntityGraphMapper.link(EntityGraphMapper.java:457)
at org.neo4j.ogm.context.EntityGraphMapper.mapEntityReferences(EntityGraphMapper.java:378)
at org.neo4j.ogm.context.EntityGraphMapper.mapEntity(EntityGraphMapper.java:222)
at org.neo4j.ogm.context.EntityGraphMapper.mapRelatedEntity(EntityGraphMapper.java:717)
at org.neo4j.ogm.context.EntityGraphMapper.link(EntityGraphMapper.java:457)
at org.neo4j.ogm.context.EntityGraphMapper.mapEntityReferences(EntityGraphMapper.java:390)
at org.neo4j.ogm.context.EntityGraphMapper.mapEntity(EntityGraphMapper.java:222)
at org.neo4j.ogm.context.EntityGraphMapper.mapRelatedEntity(EntityGraphMapper.java:717)
at org.neo4j.ogm.context.EntityGraphMapper.link(EntityGraphMapper.java:457)
at org.neo4j.ogm.context.EntityGraphMapper.mapEntityReferences(EntityGraphMapper.java:378)
at org.neo4j.ogm.context.EntityGraphMapper.mapEntity(EntityGraphMapper.java:222)
at org.neo4j.ogm.context.EntityGraphMapper.mapRelatedEntity(EntityGraphMapper.java:717)
at org.neo4j.ogm.context.EntityGraphMapper.link(EntityGraphMapper.java:457)
at org.neo4j.ogm.context.EntityGraphMapper.mapEntityReferences(EntityGraphMapper.java:390)
at org.neo4j.ogm.context.EntityGraphMapper.mapEntity(EntityGraphMapper.java:222)
at org.neo4j.ogm.context.EntityGraphMapper.mapRelatedEntity(EntityGraphMapper.java:717)
at org.neo4j.ogm.context.EntityGraphMapper.link(EntityGraphMapper.java:457)
at org.neo4j.ogm.context.EntityGraphMapper.mapEntityReferences(EntityGraphMapper.java:378)
at org.neo4j.ogm.context.EntityGraphMapper.mapEntity(EntityGraphMapper.java:222)
at org.neo4j.ogm.context.EntityGraphMapper.map(EntityGraphMapper.java:135)
at org.neo4j.ogm.session.delegates.SaveDelegate.save(SaveDelegate.java:83)
at org.neo4j.ogm.session.Neo4jSession.save(Neo4jSession.java:452)
at analysis.ModelStorage.saveModel(ModelStorage.java:42)
at analysis.Main.main(Main.java:100)
```

Answer (score 0):

I do think that your relationship direction mapping is the root cause:

In `BundleImpl` you define your relationship as `OUTGOING` and in `PackageFragmentImpl` you do the very same by skipping the direction at all. This will default to `OUTGOING`.

From the [docs](https://neo4j.com/docs/ogm-manual/current/reference/#reference:annotating-entities:relationship):

> If you don’t care about the direction then you can specify direction=Relationship.UNDIRECTED which will guarantee that the path between two node entities is navigable from either side.

Also the initial setting in both classes (`private Export exportRelation = new Export();`) of the `Export` object *could* lead to problems if you want to persist an entry without a relationship because OGM will really find a `RelationshipEntity` without any start or end node.